# Using a SVG image in iOS as background image

Tags: ios, image, swift, svg, swift2

I am using an api that gives me information along with certain images that are hosted on a media site. I get the links from these images but these are all SVG images. Now I know that iOS doesn't support SVG natively. There are a lot of libraries like pocketSVG etc but I'm not sure what to use with SWIFT. Is there any library that supports external SVG to be rendered so I can get these images and use them as UIImage?

Comment: Asking recommendation questions about libraries is slightly off topic for stackoverflow, since it can tend to evoke opinion based answers. Have a look at [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254393/810167).

Comment: As an alternative to using a UIImage, you could use a UIWebView to render an SVG.

Comment: Its not a recommendation question. I ask what I can use with SWIFT to draw/render those images from a SVG file. I don't ask what is the best. I Just give an example of those libraries that have similar functionality for Objective-C

Comment: From [Stack Overflow's Help Center > Asking page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, __software library__, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: You can also use Objective-C libraries with Swift, through the use of bridging headers.

Comment: The objective-C libraries are not well supported ( a long time before last update ) and lack of good documentation. And its also very intense for the processors which occurs in crashes according to reviews. Thats why I need a different way than those libraries.

Comment: Then try with a `UIWebView` since that will involve no extra libraries and SVGs are supported by Safari.

Comment: You don't even need a bridging header if the Objective-C library comes in as a cocoa pod and you use the use_frameworks! imperative in your Podfile. All you have to do is use an @import command.

Comment: I've written an SVG rendering library, SVGgh, in Objective-C, but I don't claim to render the entire SVG spec. It'll depend on your files. Also, presumably you'll want to download them separately before giving them to the renderer/view.